# Layout with different colors

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to have a background color of a `RelativeLayout` similar to that of an image shown in the link below. Ignore the black strip in the bottom half of the image.

[image: image 1]

I don't want to use the image as a background of the layout. Can you give me an idea of how to proceed?

Comment: What is the problem you are actually facing to do so..?

Comment: Can you upload the image? i am not able to access it from here.

Comment: @Hiral -- hey i can access the link from here..

Comment: @curiousguy: but it is blocked here as I am at job.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use gradient. Set different gradient in selector as you want. Done!

[GradientDrawable.class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)

This is what you want, set your colors. Enjoy!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:bottom="30dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
        android:topRightRadius="8dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dip" />

    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#030303"
        android:endColor="#3B3B3B"
        android:angle="270" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="30dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dip" />

    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#4B5057"
        android:endColor="#4B5059"
        android:angle="270" />
    <size android:height="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 5):

just try with shape file structure. I think this may give the solution.

Comment: can u give me an idea how to achieve this? I want a feel like there is complete separation of colors in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

//save this below code as gradient and use as background of your layout as

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

//gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#232323" android:endColor="#4B5059"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: The code you gave will make the color gradient. But i don't want that. If you check the image, there is a separation of colors in between. I want to have that kind of effect.