# How to color part of an imageview in android

Tags: android, imageview, bar-chart

I have an `ImageView` as shown below:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/barchart"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stats"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/model"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

So, this image will be basically represented in the form of an *white horizontal strip*. Now, I want to **color** its `ImageView` width depending on a *dynamic* value. If value is 30dp then, 30dp of the image will be in one color and rest 70dp will be in white color.

So, the aim is basically to represent in the form of bar chart.

Comment: Why don't you use a horizontal progressbar?

Comment: @DavidOlsson that is a feasible option but I need different colors depending on the values and that to it shouldn't move and should look like bar chart..

Comment: progressbar where you just set the progress, you can have progress color, secondary progress and no progress. So possible to have 3 colors.

Comment: Correct even that is a good option. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to override View class and draw your bars manually. Maybe even not one stripe, but entire chart. It's very easy to do. Something like this:

```
class ChartView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    List<Rect> stripes = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public ChartView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        for (Rect r : stripes) {
            paint.setColor(colors.get(stripes.indexOf(r)));
            canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course using rects to store bars is a rather bad idea. Also, you have to alter the drawing part to achieve two-color bars, but I hope you get the idea.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html

Comment: So, if we want something like above functionality, we definitely need to have two imageviews right ? I mean can't we achieve that thing using a single imageview ?

Comment: You can, using proper bitmaps or gradients, but I don't think it's a good idea to build a chart using ImageViews.

Comment: Ok. Is there any reason for not using imageview ?

Comment: Because it's a View, so it's quite heavy. Android has to measure and layout it, create textures for hardware acceleration, use sampling, antialiasing, access stripe bitmap memory and do lots of stuff just to draw white/red/blue rectangles. Custom View is always much faster and easier to maintain when it comes to complex views such as charts.

Comment: Ok. So, basically when we are dealing with canvas and stuff which is lower in level than the actual imageviews. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Possible Duplicate: [banded background with two colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727238/banded-background-with-two-colors/8731177#8731177)

You can see the both `xml` way of creating it and the `dynamic` way of setting it as well.