# Android: button with two background colors

Tags: android, button, colors, background, rounded-corners

I want to make a button style on Android with two background colors, such as the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExKXl.png

Is it possible to make with drawable resources? I´ve being searching for a solution on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html but none of them can have two colors.

Is there a way?

[editing the answer]

The solution was to create a `<layer-list>` with items and each `<item>` has one `<shape>`. The code is bellow (the entire button has 32dp height so I used half-height for each color):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Top color -->
    <item android:bottom="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> <!-- RED -->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Bottom color -->
    <item android:top="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00FF00" /> <!-- GREEN -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But I had another issue, I was trying to put corners on each shape. I tried to put `android:topLeftRadius` and `android:topRightRadius` on the first shape and `android:bottomLeftRadius` and `android:bottomRightRadius` on the second shape but it didn´t show me the corners! So the solution was to use `android:radius` (all the 8 corners became rounded, dammit!) and put another two items to overcome the extra corners. At the end the XML has like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Top color with corner -->
    <item android:bottom="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" /> <!-- It´s obligatory, It didn´t work only with android:topLeftRadius and android:topRightRadius -->
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> <!-- RED Color-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Takes off the center corner -->
    <item android:top="8dp" android:bottom="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> <!-- RED Color-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Bottom color with corner -->
    <item android:top="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp" /> <!-- It´s obligatory, It didn´t work only with android:bottomLeftRadius and android:bottomRightRadius -->
            <solid android:color="#00FF00" /> <!--  GREEN Color -->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Takes off the center corner -->
    <item android:top="16dp" android:bottom="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00FF00" /> <!--  GREEN Color -->
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

It is working now, thanks you all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [banded background with two colors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727238/banded-background-with-two-colors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible Duplicate: [banded background with two colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727238/banded-background-with-two-colors/8731177#8731177)

In which a provided answer using Java:

```
Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(buttonWidth, buttonHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient (0, 0, 0, bmResult.getHeight()/2, 0xFF284560, 0xFF284060, TileMode.MIRROR));
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient (0, 0, 0, bmResult.getHeight()/2, 0x55FFFFFF, 0x22FFFFFF, TileMode.CLAMP));
    paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(3, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bmResult.getWidth(), bmResult.getHeight()/2, paint)
```

was lifted from another SO post on the same topic: [Gradients and shadows on buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891711/gradients-and-shadows-on-buttons)

And the accepted solution using an XML drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#0000ff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And as others have said:

You can create a [9patch image](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) which would be the most resourceful.

Comment: I prefer using XML, the solution you provided worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way is to create your background using a drawing software.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this as a `<layer-list>` of two `<shape>` items (to get the boundary that the image shows).

Comment: It worked using shapes inside <layer-list> items. It is missing on Android´s documentation that <item> can have more than a <bitmap> inside. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The best fit for what you want to do is to use a [nine patch image](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch). It's how all the backgrounds of the system buttons are built. See [this](http://assets1.assembla.com/code/scala-eclipse-toolchain/git/node/blob/docs/android-examples/ApiDemos/res/drawable-hdpi/button.9.png?rev=4600152ed1f4508008491a1bf5148fe750ef1904), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [Shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and [GradientDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html)!

This works for me:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners 
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
            <size android:height="16dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f00" /> <!-- RED -->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"/>
            <size android:height="16dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f0f0" /> <!-- GREEN -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

However, [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#corners-element) said:

> Every corner must (initially) be provided a corner radius greater than
>   1, or else no corners are rounded. If you want specific corners to not
>   be rounded, a work-around is to use `android:radius` to set a default
>   corner radius greater than 1, but then override each and every corner
>   with the values you really want, providing zero ("0dp") where you
>   don't want rounded corners.

So try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners 
                android:radius="5dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
            <size android:height="16dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f00" /> <!-- RED -->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="16dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners 
                android:radius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
            <size android:height="16dp" />
            <solid android:color="#f0f0" /> <!-- GREEN -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```