# Adding percentage to gradients

Tags: android, drawable, gradient

I'm trying to create an button with xml gradient code. (Because I'm a new user can't upload the image :( ) This image has two colors and corners in its edges.The color which starts the gradient will start from 15% of all gradient length and ending color ends on 75% of gradient length.
I use this code to create Gradient with two colors:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  >
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
    android:angle="-45"
    android:startColor="#64bcfb"
    android:endColor="#2f8fd4"
     android:type="linear"/>

        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is that  i don't know how to add the start percentage and the end percentage of gradient.I have some searches about this and ind some things in:

[banded background with two colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727238/banded-background-with-two-colors)

[Gradients and shadows on buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891711/gradients-and-shadows-on-buttons)

in both there is some solutions but i it's not work for me. The solutions is about creating a simple bar with two colors but i want to create a button that have some corners in its edges also.
I cant also use the original image in my app because i need to changes its colors pragmatically.
Have any body some idea about how we can add percentages in gradients?

Answer (score 19):

This is quite old but no answer and I think I was having the issue and found a fix.

If you only need a gradient with 2 colors, a single transition and with corners, you can do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerY="0.65"
        android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

The trick here is adding a `centerColor` and `centerY` and modifying it's center. This will allow you to modify where the transition occur.

Comment: Just became a useful answer to me, centerY was what I needed to adjust the "start" point of my 2-color linear gradient. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help =)